# Migrate base R stacked bar plot to ggplot2 and distinguish bar levels with B/W structures instead of colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a table like this:

```
p_well <- structure(c(0, 0, 0.45, 0, 0, 0, 68.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.45, 0.23, 
                      0, 12.22, 0.23, 0, 0, 0, 0.23, 0.23, 1.36, 1.13, 0.23, 0, 0.23, 
                      0, 0.45, 0, 0, 0, 0.23, 0.23, 0, 0, 0.45, 0, 0.45, 0, 0.9, 0.68, 
                      0.9, 0, 1.13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0, 0, 
                      0.45, 0.23, 0, 0.45, 0.23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.88, 0, 0.45, 0, 0, 0, 
                      0.23), class = "table", .Dim = 8:9, .Dimnames = structure(list(
                        c("adjective", "as_well", "dispreferred_marker", "manner_adverb", 
                          "quote_marker", "restart_marker", "turn_preface", "unclear"
                        ), c("W1", "W2", "W3", "W4", "W5", "W6", "W7", "W8", "W9"
                        )), .Names = c("", "")))
```

and want to draw a stacked bar plot in `ggplot2`. I know how to do it in `base R`, like so:

```
par(mar = c(4.4,4,3,1))
barplot(p_well, main = "Functions of 'well' by positions in turn", cex.main = 0.9,
        cex.axis = 0.8, cex.lab = 0.8, cex.names = 0.8,
        names.arg = colnames(p_well),
        xlab = "Positions", ylab = "%",
        col = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "darkgreen", "lightblue", "blue"))
legend("topright", rownames(p_well), 
       fill =  c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "darkgreen", "lightblue", "blue"),
       bty = "n", cex = 0.8)
```

[image]

However, I would like to migrate the plot to `ggplot2`. Also, **instead of colors to distinguish the different levels of the bars, I need to use black/white structures**. How can that be done?

Comment: What do you mean by black and white structures?

Comment: By B/W 'structures' I mean something like dots, crosses, diagonals, etc. used either in addition to the shades of grey or without them to make the various bar levels more clearly distinguishable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is might be what you're looking for

```
p_well <- structure(c(0, 0, 0.45, 0, 0, 0, 68.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.45, 0.23, 
                        0, 12.22, 0.23, 0, 0, 0, 0.23, 0.23, 1.36, 1.13, 0.23, 0, 0.23, 
                        0, 0.45, 0, 0, 0, 0.23, 0.23, 0, 0, 0.45, 0, 0.45, 0, 0.9, 0.68, 
                        0.9, 0, 1.13, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.9, 0, 0.23, 0.23, 0.23, 0, 0, 
                        0.45, 0.23, 0, 0.45, 0.23, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.88, 0, 0.45, 0, 0, 0, 
                        0.23), class = "table", .Dim = 8:9, .Dimnames = structure(list(
                          c("adjective", "as_well", "dispreferred_marker", "manner_adverb", 
                            "quote_marker", "restart_marker", "turn_preface", "unclear"
                          ), c("W1", "W2", "W3", "W4", "W5", "W6", "W7", "W8", "W9"
                          )), .Names = c("", "")))

p_well <- as.data.frame(p_well)

ggplot(p_well, aes(fill=Var1, x=Var2, y=Freq )) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  xlab("Positions") +
  ylab("%") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(.8,.7))
```

[image: example]

If you want to remove the gap from the bottom

```
ggplot(p_well, aes(fill=Var1, x=Var2, y=Freq )) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  xlab("Positions") +
  ylab("%") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(.8,.7))
```

[image: example2]

You can also reverse the order using `forcats::fct_rev()` but you will also need to change the black and white colors from `scale_fill_grey(start = 0, end = .9)` to `scale_fill_grey(start = .9, end = 0)`

```
ggplot(p_well, aes(x=Var2, y=Freq,fill = forcats::fct_rev(Var1))) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity") +
  xlab("Positions") +
  ylab("%") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .9, end = 0) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(.8,.7))
```

[image: example3]

Do add patterns to the plot you can use `ggpattern()`. However, using a black and white scale and the size of some of the bars, it makes it difficult to tell the difference between the groups

```
library(ggpattern)
ggplot(p_well, aes(x=Var2, y=Freq)) + 
  geom_bar_pattern(position="stack",stat="identity",
                   mapping=aes(pattern=Var1)) +
  xlab("Positions") +
  ylab("%") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .9, end = 0) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(.8,.7))
```

[image: example4]

To have the color of the fill to vary in different shades of grey

```
ggplot(p_well, aes(x=Var2, y=Freq, fill=Var1)) + 
  geom_bar_pattern(position="stack",stat="identity",
                   mapping=aes(pattern=Var1)) +
  xlab("Positions") +
  ylab("%") +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_fill_grey(start = .9, end = 0) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(.8,.7))
```

[image: example5]

Comment: Looks good but I can't reproduce the plot. Could it be that there's some code missing? For example, in `p_well`there's not `Var1` and `Var2`. Also, I'm thinking of B/W **structures** not shades of grey. By 'structure' I mean something like dots, crosses, diagonals, etc.

Comment: I apologize, I just converted `p_well` into a data frame using `p_well <- as.data.frame(p_well)`. I wasn't sure if there was an issue with your example data or my importing of the data

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann Updated my answer so you can see exactly what I did

Comment: Well done, thanks for the clarification. Now all that's missing are the B/W **structures** to distinguish the bar levels. By 'structure' I mean something like dots, crosses, diagonals, etc.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I added that to my answer. It just doesn't look the best. You can use `ggpattern()` to add the structures. There are other designs you can use but they are hard to see because of the size of some of the groups

Comment: Yes you're right. The patterns do not add to visual clarity. Does the background shade have to be same?

Comment: Sorry about that. Hopefully, you can figure out a greyscale color scheme to distinguish the different groups.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann How does the most recent edit look?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann You will probably need to play with the patterns a bit to find the best fit

Comment: See here https://coolbutuseless.github.io/package/ggpattern/articles/geom-gallery-geometry.html#geom-density-pattern-

Comment: Just one more Q: I cannot install the package `ggpattern`although I have updated R to the latest version. Is there any trick for doing it?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann `install.packages("remotes")`
`remotes::install_github("trevorld/gridpattern")`
`remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")` Let me know if one of those work